# Java equivalent of Ruby's Tilt

Tags: java

The Ruby community has produced a lovely library called [Tilt](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt). It's basically an abstraction over template engines, so that rather than supporting individual templating engines, a web framework only has to support Tilt, and by doing so supports everything Tilt supports.

Does Java offer anything similar? Possibly as a Servlet component, possibly not -- not sure if it's relevant yet.

I'm prototyping my own web framework, and rather than implementing adapters for a smattering of template engines (rewriting that particular wheel, again), it'd be great to implement just one abstraction.

Comment: On a tangent, you may want to look at [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com). You write **pure Java code for a web app**. You define layouts/forms, fields, buttons, and other UI widgets all in Java. You write no HTML, CSS, JavaScript, DOM, XML, JSON. **No templates.** Vaadin auto-generates at runtime the necessary HTML, CSS, and JavaScript to render your desired UI in the client’s web browser using **standard web technologies**. User actions client-side trigger your Java code on the server-side to execute in the Java Servlet container such as Tomcat. Amazing stuff. Not new, in production many years.

Comment: Given that it doesn't do anything that I want, that seems like an especially off-the-wall tangent. Thanks anyway...